# Linked Server Timeout - Not Queried

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server, jobs

I have a job that runs for multiple regions across the globe. Depending on what region is running and what time zone it's in, the job might not run. It uses `GOTO` to get to the end and reports that it was skipped due to time and completes.

This runs as expected with no issues.

The Issue: there are times when a linked server farther down the proc is under really heavy load. We know about it and cannot avoid it - so we don't query the linked server at this time.

But, we're still getting an error as if it's queried:

> Cannot obtain the schema rowset "DBSCHEMA_TABLES_INFO" for OLE DB
>   provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server   returned message "Unspecified
>   error". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for
>   linked server   returned message "Query timeout expired". [SQLSTATE
>   01000] (Error 7412).  The step failed.

Are linked servers validated when a proc starts causing this schema check that times out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a  guess, but I would try enabling lazy schema validation for the linked server under heavy load:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'Linked_Server_name', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'true'
```

> If this option is set to false, the default value, SQL Server checks
>   for schema changes that have occurred since compilation in remote
>   tables. This check occurs before query execution. If there is a change
>   in the schema, SQL Server recompiles the query with the new schema.
>
> If this option is set to true, schema checking of remote tables is
>   delayed until execution. This can cause a distributed query to fail
>   with an error if the schema of a remote table has changed between
>   query compilation and execution.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190918(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

As to only check the linked server metadata when querying the linked server itself.

Another workaround could be using dynamic sql statements to query the linked server

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
IF (Linked Server not under heavy load = true)
BEGIN
SET @SQL = 
N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer,''SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases'')'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
END
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL is an awesome suggestion - I should have thought of that! Delaying the check, while a good one, would cause headaches down the road - I can already feel them coming on!

Comment: @TonyBasallo Thank you for the feedback :)